# jquery cannot toggle visibility of an image nested 4 levels down, but works 3 levels down

Tags: jquery, html

I have an ajaxloader.gif inside 4 nested Divs, Hidden, and when the scollbar hits bottom, I make it visible and load more.

```
<div class="doc-section clearfix" id="grid" style="margin-bottom:60px;">
  <div class="example-grid">
    <div class="four columns alpha" style="padding:4px;background-color:#FFC;">
      <div id="LoaderOverlay"  style="display:none;"  align="center">
     <img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Jquery

```
function onScroll(event) {
   // Check if we're within 100 pixels of the bottom edge of the broser window.
   var closeToBottom = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200);
   if(closeToBottom) {
    $('#myFeed li:last').each(function() 
          { 
        $("#LoaderOverlay").show();
        getMore(ID);

      });
  }
};

 $(document).ready(new function() {
      // Capture scroll event.
      $(window).bind('scroll', onScroll);
    });
```

Strangely, the Gif cannot be turned on inside 4 divs. But if I make it 3 divs, then it works. I can very well make it so, but I am curious why this happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you call $("#LoaderOverlay").parent().show() in addition? It could be simply that that 'third level' is hidden/otherwise invisible and that's why the show() had an effect there.

Comment: Are you sure that this is not an issue with layout? Maybe hide/show methods work, but you just don't see this div because of something else. Did you try to verify what style this div has after you invoke show method?

Comment: @outcoldman after the method, it still shows display:none;

Comment: @struthersneil I checked to make sure that all parent divs are ok. I could nt get to test your method, but will do that soon.